# how to view azure diagnostics Log

Tags: azure, azure-storage, azure-table-storage

I am not able to find out how to see azure diagnostics logs. Code which I wrote is as follows.

```cs
DiagnosticMonitorConfiguration config = iagnosticMonitor.GetDefaultInitialConfiguration();
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
config.Logs.ScheduledTransferLogLevelFilter = LogLevel.Information;
config.WindowsEventLog.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);
DiagnosticMonitor.Start("Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Plugins.Diagnostics.ConnectionString", config);
```

then I added `Trace.WriteLine("some message");` in the code. Now where do I find those messages. I checked in Visual Studio server explorer, where I added my storage account reference. wad-control-container has only config files.

Comment: I found this link to be very helpful: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/magazine/ff714589.aspx

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You might want to take a look at this blog post by Michael S. Collier. A setting in your cloud project might cause the logs to end up in an other place than you would expect them to:

http://michaelcollier.wordpress.com/2012/04/02/where-is-my-windows-azure-diagnostics-data/

**Update:**

Note that you'll have to take care of every small detail to make everything work.

Where are you writing `Trace.WriteLine("some message");` ? Is it in your WebRole.cs? If that's the case, you'll need to configure the trace listener for the WebRole.cs (this runs in an other process, different than your actual web application).

Here is an example how you can set up the trace listener in the WebRole.cs class:

```
System.Diagnostics.Trace.Listeners.Add(new Microsoft.WindowsAzure.Diagnostics.DiagnosticMonitorTraceListener());
System.Diagnostics.Trace.AutoFlush = true;
```

After setting that up, you can use **Trace.WriteLine**.

Comment: I checked the settings. All are proper. Acording to the code I posted above, where can I find the Trace messages? is it in "WADLogsTable"?. I read it in some blogs.

Comment: I have written `Trace.WriteLine("some message");` in the worker role. i only have worker role in my project. And I have added the Trace Listerners also. One more thing I observed is, i found some table files (.tsf files) getting created in `"C:\Users\Administrator\AppData\Local\dftmp\s0\deployment(350)\res\de‌​ployment(350).TCPServerTester.TCPServerRole.0\directory\DiagnosticStore\Monitor\T‌​ables"` directory. But no `WADLogsTable` in the storage.

Comment: Are you using the developer storage or a real storage account? Did you notice that you are setting the interval for the WindowsEventLogs and not for the regular Logs? You should also set it for the regular Logs. And could you try changing it to 5 minutes.

Comment: Yeah I got the mistake. As you said I was setting the interval for WindowsEventLogs. I changed it to `config.Logs.ScheduledTransferPeriod = System.TimeSpan.FromMinutes(1.0);` and it works now.. Thanks a lot..

Comment: If you would like to view & dissect the TSF files, you can use this link: http://blogs.msdn.com/b/kwill/archive/2013/08/26/azuretools-the-diagnostic-utility-used-by-the-windows-azure-developer-support-team.aspx  ...specifically the table2csv utility.

Answer (score 1):

This is a good step by step on how to enable diagnostics:

http://www.windowsazure.com/en-us/develop/net/common-tasks/diagnostics/?sec=commontasks

Answer (score 0):

I wrote a tool that allows you to view Azure Diagnostic information.. check it out

[AzTools - Azure Diagnostic Viewer](http://sudxtrm.com/2013/08/making-azure-simple-aztools/)

[Click here to see how you could use this tool](http://sudxtrm.com/aztools/how-does-this-work/)

Comment: This tool appears to be down.